# Deduplicate results in elasticsearch based on a field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, grouping

I have an elasticsearch index (v6.8) that contains documents that may share a similar value for a field.

```
[
    { 
        "siren": 123,
        "owner": "A",
        "price": 10
    },
    { 
        "siren": 123,
        "owner": "B",
        "price": 20
    },
    { 
        "siren": 456,
        "owner": "A",
        "price": 10
    },
    { 
        "siren": 456,
        "owner": "C",
        "price": 30
    } 
]
```

I would like to get all documents from owner A and B, but deduplicated on the siren field. The result would be. I don't care which deduplicated line is returned (from owner A or B).

```
[
    { 
        "siren": 123,
        "owner": "A",
        "price": 10
    },
    { 
        "siren": 456,
        "owner": "A",
        "price": 10
    }
]
```

Also, I would like my aggregations to count documents deduplicated on the same field.

I have tried

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "owner": [
                                "A",
                                "B"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_price": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "price",
                "size": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this counts multiple times the "same" document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use terms aggregation on the `siren` field along with top hits aggregation

```
 {
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "owner.keyword": [
              "A",
              "B"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_price": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "siren",
        "size": 20
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "siren",
                "owner",
                "price"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_price": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 123,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_sales_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "66226467",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "owner": "A",          // note this
                    "siren": 123,
                    "price": 10
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 456,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_sales_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "66226467",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "owner": "A",       // note this
                    "siren": 456,
                    "price": 10
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Hakim please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your use case ?

Comment: Thanks it works, but unfortunately I can't scroll on it